# cvCaptureFromCam is working but cvQueryFrame returns NULL

Tags: opencv

I have seen most people have problems with cvCaptureFromCam where as for me cvCaptureFromCam(-1) is working fine and returning a non-null pointer; however cvQueryFrame is returning NULL. To go in details I used cvGrabFrame and cvRetrieveFrame. cvGrabFrame is returning 1 that means its successfully grabbed the frame but cvRetrieveFrame returned NULL. 
Can somebody please guide me.

Comment: I'm going to refer to an old answer I gave some time ago. The trick is: ignore the first frame from `cvQueryFrame`, and then read all the other frames in a loop. Notice how I don't store the result of the first call to cvQueryFrame. Check this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231497/capture-video-from-camera-in-mac-os-x/3258540#3258540

Comment: This doesn't help in my case.  Same setup as above, only I am using it on Android.  Does anybody have any insight?